# File is not included in the TypeScript compilation context

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, tsconfig

Using Atom editor with the typescript plug I'm getting the following error:

> Error The file "D:/foo/app/classes/event.class.ts" is not included in
>   the TypeScript compilation context.  If this is not intended, please
>   check the "files" or "filesGlob" section of your tsconfig.json file.at
>   line 1 col 1

The contents of my tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

I have looked at a few others that have had this problem.  This: https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/issues/4 got me to try building a "files" array in the tsconfig.json array.  That, much like with the person in the other thread, did not help.  Note, that thread talked a lot of about testing... which doesn't apply for me.

I also tried parsing through this thread: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/558 however that basically ended up being an argument about purity vs pragmatism.  I did pick up that if the files and filesGlob arrays are missing, an implicit "everything" glob is used.  If this were the case, why am I getting the error given I don't have a file and filesGlob entry.

As an aside, command-line TSC is generating the compiled js and map files just fine. ... but I still have to see the big red error in Atom.

For what it's worth, the event.class.ts file looks like this (I don't expect this is the source of the problem, but figured I'd include it for completeness):

```
import {Utilities} from '../utilities';

export class Event {
    eventData:JSON;
    eventID:string;

    constructor(_eventData:JSON, _eventID?:string) {
        if(_eventID==null) {
            _eventID=Utilities.newGuidPlus();
        }
        this.eventID = _eventID;
        this.eventData = _eventData;
    }


    getEventData():JSON { // returns the full event
        return this.eventData;
    }

    getEventID():string {
        return this.eventID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Renaming the files and folder works for one run and then it starts all over again. Not sure if it is an Atom or Typescript transpiler problem.

Comment: Hmm I have the same problem. Did you ever solve the problem??

Comment: I simply started a new project based on the angular2 quickstart.  I believe the problem is with Atom trying to transpile and command-line transpiling at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the exact issue in my case, I included `"**/*.ts"` in ***“filesGlob”*** property in **tsconfig.json** to resolve. The whole tsconfig.json looks like this.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSources": true
  },

  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],

  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For my case, the solution was different:

1. Ensure that ALL files in your project have ALL the imports well written. (Case sensitive)
2. Save all files. Close Atom. <s>Restart your Computer.</s> (Not necessary)
3. Open Atom again. Done. :)

I will update if something else occurs with this bug.

Comment: Thanks for that - this issue had been irritating me for days. The file throwing the error in my case was /src/util/configureRouter.ts but the import was as follows: import configureRouter from '../utils/configureRouter';
It would help if the error gave a little more information if possible.

Comment: Yep simply a case sensitive look up. Worked for me too. I like the idea that is checks if it is cased correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue with `atom`, in my case a ts file in a hidden directory was not being compiled. Explicitly adding the path in `tsconfig.json` resolved the issue:

```
"filesGlob": [
  "**/*.ts",
  ".serverless_plugins/**/*.ts",
  "!node_modules/**"
],
```